# How to get data for one to many relationship using Eloquent in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to get data for one to many relationship using Eloquent in Laravel? Actually I followed [Eloquent Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships). But my code returns me an empty array. Here's my work:

**Database Schema**

Parent Table: **mtg_workspace** with columns (mw_id[primary key], mw_name,..., mw_access)

Child Table: **mtg_workspace_amenities** with columns (id[primary key], wa_mwid, wa_name)

Model: **MtgWorkspace.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MtgWorkspace extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'mtg_workspace';
  public $timestamps = false;

  public function MtgWorkspaceAmenities(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\MtgWorkspaceAmenities', 'wa_mwid');
  }
}
```

Model: **MtgWorkspaceAmenities.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MtgWorkspaceAmenities extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'mtg_workspace_amenities';
  public $timestamps = false;

  public function MtgWorkspace(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\MtgWorkspace');
  }
}
```

Controller: **WorkspaceController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\MtgWorkspace;
use App\MtgWorkspaceAmenities;

class WorkspaceController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
   {
      $workspace = MtgWorkspace::with('MtgWorkspaceAmenities')->get();

      return $workspace;
    }
}
```

and here it shows following output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try defining the primary key for the `MtgWorkspace` model (as it is not `id`):

```
protected $primaryKey = 'mw_id';
```

I don't think it can match up the children `MtgWorkspaceAmenities` to the parent `MtgWorkspace` models as it is trying to use the `id` attribute on `MtgWorkspace` to match to the foreign key on `MtgWorkspaceAmenities` when it spins through the result of the eager loading.

Side Note:

You will have to pass more parameters to the inverse relationship on `MtgWorkSpaceAmenities` when defining it, as `belongsTo()` wants to use the calling methods name snake cased with `_id` added if not told otherwise as the key.